# 00907. 00000 - "missing right parenthesis" NOT ABLE TO CREATE THIS TABLE?

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE PROGRAMS
(
    PROG_ID NOT NULL NUMBER(3),
    PROG_COST NUMBER(8,2),
    START_DATE NOT NULL DATE,
    END_DATE DATE
);
```

Comment: What dbms is this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be Oracle, `NOT NULL` must be defined *after* the data type.

```
CREATE TABLE PROGRAMS
(
    PROG_ID NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    PROG_COST NUMBER(8,2),
    START_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    END_DATE DATE
);
```

Comment: duplicate answer as above

Comment: @GaganBurde: Yep, I answered a minute earlier :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using oracle database the syntax for creating table is

```
CREATE TABLE table_name

( 

 column1 datatype [ NULL | NOT NULL ],


  column2 datatype [ NULL | NOT NULL ],

  ...
  column_n datatype [ NULL | NOT NULL ]

);
```

so in your case

```
CREATE TABLE PROGRAMS

(
   PROG_ID  NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,

    PROG_COST NUMBER(8,2),

    START_DATE DATE  NOT NULL,

    END_DATE DATE
);
```